# Symfony2 didn't display my translation

Tags: php, symfony

i have actually a problem when i use symfony translator. I followed the doc of Symfony2 translator and i created this repertory 
=> myBundle/PlatformBundle/Ressources/translations 
and in translations i have created this file 
=> messages.fr.yml: `Hello: Bonjour`
I have a twig like that:

```
<html>
  <body>
    {{ 'Hello'|trans }} {{ name }}!
    <p> Sonate cest cool mais la trad sa lest deja moins </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and i have conf my config.yml like the doc say.

Unfortunately, it's doesn't work and i don't understand why ?

Comment: You have to clear the cache before using a new translation file. Type *php app/console ca:cl* and try again.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried to clear the cache but...

Comment: Your twig file is located in the PlatformBundle?

Comment: my twig => src/Kayser/PlatformBundle/Resources/view/Default/test.html.twig

Comment: Maybe the problem comes that i created manually the repertory "translations" ?

Comment: Ressources or Resources? Needs to be Resources...

Comment: in app/config/parameters.yml you can try to set parameters:    locale: fr     it sets default locale to fr. And are you sure of the directory you created myBundle/PlatformBundle/Ressources/translations ?

Answer (score 1):

if you have followed french official doc for translation maybe you have set translator like this in config.yml :

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

Try to do like this:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: fr }
```

Or better like this :
framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }

and in this last case, edit your app/config/parameters.yml and specify the default locale like this :

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

If this not sufficient, then verify your directory myBundle/PlatformBundle/Ressources/translations is correct.

Comment: Ok ty, the problem was in my parameters.yml cause i had 2 line "locale :"